# Second Instance Installation of PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, installation

Relating to original question posted on Stack Overflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59002035/distribution-installation-and-connectivity-of-postgresql).

Interested in distributing a copy of PostgreSQL with a C# app (for Windows). However, trying to understand how the following scenario should be handled:

- PostgreSQL already installed on the user's system

From my understanding, should be possible to install a 2nd instance of PostgreSQL to run at the same time on the same computer system (as a different service, bound to a different TCP port #?). However, the closest answer for how this would be done was found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/6BCB9D8A16AC4241919521715F4D8BCE6C7A2D%40algol.sollentuna.se), which does not really provide a lot of detail.

So far, in my test environment (VM), I have one instance of Ver. 12 PostgreSQL installed in the default directory `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12`.

Am I correct to understand that I should copy all of the contens of the `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12` directory and copy/paste to a different directory (e.g. `C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\Test12`?

Then, run `pg_ctl register`, but with what options?

And, then after, I should run `pg_ctl start`?

Are there any considerations that should be made before all of this is done?

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37861262/create-multiple-postgres-instances-on-same-machine

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need the binaries two times, you only need to create a second [data directory](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/creating-cluster.html) (aka "cluster").

The following creates a new data directory under `c:\ProgramData\pgdata2`. I **highly** recommend to **not** put the data directory under `c:\Program Files` (that's one of the reasons I stopped using the EntpriseDB installer because it always suggested that)

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\initdb" -D "c:\ProgramData\pgdata2"
```

Then edit `c:\ProgramData\pgdata2\postgresql.conf` and change the value for `port`, e.g.

```
port = 5335
```

Then you can register the new Windows service and provide the data directory during registration:

```
pg_ctl register -N other-postgres -D "c:\ProgramData\pgdata2"
```

Once the service is registered, you can start it using `net start`

```
net start other-postgres
```

Comment: If you don't use the EnterpriseDB installer, which one do you use?

Comment: @Vérace: I use the [ZIP files](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgbindownload) to install Postgres I essentially do what I described in this answer (after unzipping the archive).

Comment: Followed the steps to the T, but when trying to connect with psql with the following command: psql -h localhost -p 5433, I am getting a "connection refused." I see both port 5432 and 5433 occupied by postgres.exe (running netstat). 5432 is my original instance and 5433 is my 2nd instance.

Comment: *Face-palm* I forgot to uncomment the listen_addresses = 'localhost' config. setting.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - I did that last weekend, but I was worried about any potential performance hits? I take it there aren't any?

Comment: @Vérace: there is no difference. The installer does essentially the same thing

Comment: I needed to set listen_addresses = '*', even for same-machine access.  My machine has two IP address (LAN and corporate).