# Permission denied to create new tablespace for PostgreSQL data

Tags: postgresql, permissions

I can't set my PostgreSQL data folder to a drive other than the C drive (Windows 8 machine).

1) If I try to do so when installing PostgreSQL, the installation fails. Therefore I need to choose the C drive to make installation work.

2) If I try to create a tablespace in the D drive, I am not allowed to do so. Permission error pops up.

```
   CREATE TABLESPACE drive_D
   OWNER postgres
   LOCATION 'D:\PostgreSQL\data'
```

I get the following error:

```
   ERROR:  could not set permissions on directory "D:/PostgreSQL/data": Permission denied
   SQL state: 42501
```

I am an admin on that machine and I gave 'NETWORK SERVICE' full control on the D drive, but that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: Did you try to initialize the database cluster manually using `initdb`? I have absolutely no problems putting the data directory to a different drive. See e.g. [here](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/254085/) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61115811) for an example

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand those two links. I have no idea what those instructions do. I have followed the steps anyway, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Installer: 12.2 for Windows 64 / D drive is internal / Filesystem: NTFS

Comment: Yes  =>  https://www.enterprisedb.com/downloads/postgres-postgresql-downloads

Comment: It works for me on Windows 10 with NTFS.  I don't have Windows 8 myself, nor can I rent Windows 8 (that I can find anyway) on AWS in order to test it.  But I think it should work on 8, so maybe something about your installation history or configuration has created a conflict.  Can you get a clean Windows 8 box and try it there as a test?

Comment: We have ten machines in the office, all of them with the same setup. The issue happens in all of them. If something has created a conflict I guess it'd be very unlikely it happened in all 10 machines?