# "Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster" when installing PostgreSQL 12.3 in a drive other than C

Tags: postgresql

When I try to install PostgreSQL 12.3 in a drive other than C, I get the following error message:

```
"Failed to load SQL modules into the database cluster"
```

I have previously raised a related issue ([Permission denied to create new tablespace for PostgreSQL data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/266930/permission-denied-to-create-new-tablespace-for-postgresql-data?noredirect=1#comment525826_266930)), but no one has been able to help so far.

NOTE: Before running the pg installation program, I have made sure that the user 'NETWORK SERVICE' has full control on the folder (whole drive actually) where I want to save my pg data.

Comment: Is the drive where you want to install PostgreSQL on a local disk or a network file system? I don't know much about Windows, but I have seen cases where it tries to "protect" the user by refusing to run executables stored on network drives.

Comment: The drive is on a local disk.